# How can I use Google API for translate?

Tags: android, google-translate

I want to make a translater, but when I copy any sample to my project, I always get an exception or compile error in my project. I tried many samples from github or youtube tutorial source code.

Example: http://android-er.blogspot.in/2009/10/androidtranslate-using-google-translate.html

When I copy and paste the following into the project:

```
import com.google.api.translate.Language;
import com.google.api.translate.Translate;
```

The imports are always unused. By the way, `apı` is marked in red. How can I use correctly use Google's API?

Mainactivity.class:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.api.translate.Language;
import com.google.api.translate.Translate;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText MyInputText;
    Button MyTranslateButton;
    TextView MyOutputText;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        MyInputText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.InputText);
        MyTranslateButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.TranslateButton);
        MyOutputText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.OutputText);

        MyTranslateButton.setOnClickListener(MyTranslateButtonOnClickListener);

    }
    private Button.OnClickListener MyTranslateButtonOnClickListener
            = new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String InputString;
            String OutputString = null;
            InputString = MyInputText.getText().toString();

            try {
                Translate.setHttpReferrer("http://android-er.blogspot.com/");
                OutputString = Translate.execute(InputString,
                        Language.ENGLISH, Language.FRENCH);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                OutputString = "Error";
            }

            MyOutputText.setText(OutputString);

        }

    };




}
```

Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" ></uses-permission>
```

The rest of the codes is only layout (there is only one layout).

Comment: What do you mean by unused? It is maybe just the IDE telling you that you currently are not using the class you are importing? And did you add the library to your gradle dependencies? We can't really work without the code and gradle files.

Comment: You can click to my link for my source code. I just copıed and pasted 3 pages from there. I know how to import library but I always get exception.(And there is no library link there.İf there is I dont see it.)If there is another problem to my importing I have not any idea.

Comment: Did you also follow the instructions in the articel linked in the article you mentioned (http://android-er.blogspot.de/2009/10/google-api-translate-java.html)? I guess you forgot that step, thus the library is not included.

Comment: Additionally the article says right at the top that the API is now a paid API for which you should refer to https://cloud.google.com/translate/ - after all the article is *8* years old

Comment: Yes.I clicked download link but I can not establish because I using macbook and this is not authorized. I just want to use translator of Google. easily.

Comment: Well theres your problem then. Follow the tutorial. And - like I said - the tutorial is from 2010 and thus very much outdated, refer to https://cloud.google.com/translate/ for the current implementation.

Answer (score 0):

As Ch4t4r mentioned, the tutorial you've linked is from 2009 and not relevant anymore.

The current Cloud Translation API Client Libraries are documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries), however it states:

> Note: Google Cloud Java client libraries do not currently support Android.

You'll need to call the [Cloud Translation REST API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/rest) directly. It is quite straightforward to use and you should get it to work in no time with your preferred HTTP library (e.g. [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)).